# How to save graphql user token in jmeter

Tags: graphql, jmeter

My application uses graphql. I need to create tests in jmeter, where all requests will be, from creating a user to deleting him. But I can't deliver and substitute a token in every request.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZLAD.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8U7t.png)
Here the token is not substituted, although it should if I do everything correctly:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bopK.png)

Answer (score 0):

We cannot help you without seeing the full response from the `SignIn` call and the [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-header-manager) configuration.

If your [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) expression doesn't return any match it will return an empty value instead, to check if this is the case - you can provide a default value to return when there is no match, i.e. `NOT_FOUND`

[image]

and then if you see that your [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header is `Bearer NOT_FOUND` then something is wrong with your JsonPath expression

Comment: Yes, if I add the default value NOT_FOUND, I see it substituted instead of the token, you are right, sir.

{"data":{"userSignIn":{"accessToken":"%%this_Is_token%%","__typename":"UserCredentialsGqlType"}}}